# ZIO Streams: Which is the difference between a ZSink and a ZTransducer?

Tags: scala, zio, zio-streams

I'm studying ZIO Streams, using version 1.0.9 of the library `zio-streams`.
I cannot find any reference that shows me the difference between a `ZSink` and a `ZTransducer`.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ZSink` is a used to consume elements from the `ZStream`. In turn a sink will cause the materialization of the entire stream to run through and produce a value.

A `ZTransducer` is a stateful function which processes *chunks* of data in the stream, and in contrast to a `ZSink` it's processing never ends.

If we look at a trivial example:

```
import zio.stream.{ ZSink, ZStream }
import zio.stream.ZTransducer.{ splitLines, utf8Decode }

import java.nio.file.Paths

ZStream
  .fromFile(Paths.get("/foo"), chunkSize = 1024 * 4)
  .transduce(utf8Decode >>> splitLines)
  .run(ZSink.foreach(zio.console.putStr))
```

We can see that the new `ZStream` encoding is chunk based, and using `transduce` with `utf8Decode` which decodes a chunk of bytes to String and then splits them by line. Finally, we use the `.run` method and supply a `ZSink` which emits data to the console, element by element.

More on the new design of ZStream [can be found here.](https://github.com/zio/zio/issues/3347)

Comment: Many thanks. So, if we have to transform values of a stream, but we want to maintain their cardinality, we use `map` (or its variants). If we want to transform both the values and the cardinality of chunks, we use a `ZTransducer`. Finally, if we want to consume the values of a stream, we use a `ZSink`. Have I understood right?

Comment: @riccardo.cardin The question of cardinality of an unbounded stream is a difficult one. In that sense, AFAIU, there shouldn't be a change to cardinality even if your stream is bounded. A `ZTransducer` will provide you with the chance to operate on chunks of data instead of on an element by element basis.

Comment: Many thanks. The current version of ZStreams uses _implicit chunking_; you're right. The only way to work explicitly with chunks is to use a `ZTransducer`. Maybe, you could add this last consideration to your answer :)